# How to use the root route (/) as /admin in strapi

Tags: strapi

I want to open my subdomain admin.example.com and get directly to the admin login page, without the index.html page that comes before and tells me the page is in production environment, to improve usability to the customer and avoid something stupid like admin.example.com/admin.

Maybe I could do it with middlewares, but I'm clueless.

I'm using heroku.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently **not** supported.

> Currently we don't support serving the admin from the root, added as a feature request

See https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/9302

### Workaround

You can redirect `/` to `/admin` with a [custom middleware](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html#middlewares).

#### Create the middleware

You may need to create the directory (`mkdir -p middlewares/redirect/`).

```js
// middlewares/redirect/index.js

module.exports = () => {
  return {
    initialize() {
      strapi.router.get('/', (ctx) => {
        ctx.redirect(strapi.config.get('server.admin.url', '/admin'))
      })
    },
  };
};
```

#### Enable it

```js
// config/middleware.js

module.exports = {
  settings: {
    redirect: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are there any updates for 2023?